# Using different controllers with custom directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a search box which is being used on two different views, one is for searching jobs and the other is for searching companies. I have made two separate controllers for both and separate services as well.

Here is the html for the searchbox -

```
<span class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i></span>
<input ng-change="companies.search()" 
       ng-model="companies.searchTerm" 
       ng-keydown="companies.deleteTerm($event)" 
       type="text" id="search-box" 
       style="width: 0px; visibility:hidden;"/>
```

Here is a script i am using for styling it -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var toggleVar = true;
    $('.searchButton').on('click', function() {
        if(toggleVar) {
            $('.searchButton').animate({right: '210px'}, 400);
            $('#search-box').css("visibility", "visible");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.searchButton').css("color", "#444444");
            }, 200);
            $('#search-box').animate({ width: 185 }, 400).focus();
            toggleVar = false;
        }
        else {
            $('#search-box').animate({ width: 0 }, 400);
            $('.searchButton').animate({right: '25px'}, 400);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.searchButton').css("color", "#eeeeee");
            }, 300);
            toggleVar = true;
        }
    });

    $('#search-box').focusout(function() {
        if(!toggleVar) {
            $('#search-box').animate({ width: 0 }, 400);
            $('.searchButton').animate({right: '25px'}, 400);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.searchButton').css("color", "#eeeeee");
            }, 300);
            toggleVar = true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Controller -

```
angular.module('jobSeekerApp')
  .controller('CompaniesallCtrl', ['getAllCompanies', function (companiesService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var count;
    ctrl.pageNumber = 1;
    ctrl.searchPageNumber = 1;
    ctrl.isSearching = false;
    ctrl.searchTerm = "";

    // Initial page load
    companiesService.getCompanies(ctrl.pageNumber)
      .then(function(response) {
        ctrl.companiesList = response.data.results;
        count = response.data.count;
        checkCount();
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    // User clicks next button
    ctrl.getNext = function() {
      // If search is not being used
      if(ctrl.searchTerm === "" && ctrl.isSearching === false) {
        ctrl.pageNumber = ctrl.pageNumber + 1;
        companiesService.getCompanies(ctrl.pageNumber)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.companiesList = ctrl.companiesList.concat(response.data.results);
            checkCount(); 
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      // If search is being used
      else {
        ctrl.searchPageNumber = ctrl.searchPageNumber + 1;
        companiesService.searchCompany(ctrl.searchPageNumber, ctrl.searchTerm)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.companiesList = ctrl.companiesList.concat(response.data.results);
            checkCount();
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } 
    };

    // User backspaces to delete search term
    ctrl.deleteTerm = function (event) {
      if(event.keyCode === 8) {
        ctrl.searchTermLen = ctrl.searchTermLen - 1;
      }
      // If search box is empty
      ctrl.isSearching = ctrl.searchTermLen !== 0;
    };

    // User clicks search button
    ctrl.search = function() {
      ctrl.searchTermLen = ctrl.searchTerm.length;
      // If search box is empty, show normal results
      if(ctrl.searchTerm === "" && ctrl.isSearching === false) {
        ctrl.pageNumber = 1;
        companiesService.getCompanies(ctrl.pageNumber)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.companiesList = response.data.results;
            count = response.data.count;
            checkCount();
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      // If search box is not empty, search the input
      else {
        ctrl.isSearching = true;
        ctrl.searchPageNumber = 1;
        companiesService.searchCompany(ctrl.searchPageNumber, ctrl.searchTerm)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.companiesList = response.data.results;
            count = response.data.count;
            checkCount();
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    };

    // Function to hide and show next button
    function checkCount() {
      console.log(count);
      $(".nextButton").toggle(count > 10);
      count = count - 10;
    }
  }]);
```

I am trying to make a directive for this, since all this code is being repeated for the both the views. But how do I make the directive interact with different controllers. And how do i make this part `ng-change="companies.search()" ng-model="companies.searchTerm" ng-keydown="companies.deleteTerm($event)"` not dependent on the controllers.
I am new to angular and am not sure if this is the right approach or should i let the keep the code separate? Please help.

Comment: Can you share the controllers also please

Comment: I have added the controller for one of the views, the others have the same functions but different data is being handled by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server-Side search logic makes it simple**

If it is possible that your search logic resides on the server and searching jobs or companies could be distinguished by simply setting a query variable in the URL, then it easy.  You could use 1 search directive with an attribute to say which module to search and include this in your HTTP request.

**Client-Side search logic slightly more angularjs**

If you need different client-side logic for each type of search,  consider this approach where there is 1 common `search` directive, plus 1 directive for each customized search.

1. the common search directive controls view + common search functionality
2. a search-companies directive that is `restrict: 'A'` and `require: 'search'` and performs functions specific to the company search
3. a search-jobs directive that is also `restrict: 'A'` and `require: 'search'` and performs functions specific to the job search

The concept is that the custom search directives will provide their controller/api object to the common search directive.  The common search directive handles the view-controller interaction and calls the provided API functions for customized search functionality.

**In Code**, this could look something like:

```
angular.module('SearchDemo', [])
.directive('search', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/search.tpl.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.results = [];

            this.setSearchAPI = function(searchAPI){
                this.api = searchAPI;
            };

            $scope.doSearch = function(query){
                $scope.results.length = 0;

                // here we call one of the custom controller functions
                if(this.api && angular.isFunction(this.api.getResults)){
                    var results = this.api.getResults(query);

                    // append the results onto $scope.results
                    // without creating a new array
                    $scope.results.push.apply($scope.results, results);
                }
            };
        }]
    };
})
.directive('searchCompanies', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['search', 'searchCompanies'],
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, Ctrl){
            // here we pass the custom search-companies controller
            // to the common search controller
            Ctrl[0].setSearchAPI(Ctrl[1]);
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            // you need to design your common search API and 
            // implement the custom versions of those functions here

            // example:
            this.getResults = function(query){
                // TODO: load the results for company search
            };
        }]
    };
})
.directive('searchJobs', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['search', 'searchJobs'],
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, Ctrl){
            // here we pass the custom search-jobs controller
            // to the common search controller
            Ctrl[0].setSearchAPI(Ctrl[1]);
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            // you need to design your common search API and 
            // implement the custom versions of those functions here

            // example:
            this.getResults = function(query){
                // TODO: load the results for job search
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

And using it in template would look like:

`<search search-companies></search>`

and

`<search search-jobs></search>`

**Multiple searches on one directive**

This concept could be easily expanded if you need to have one search directive that searches both companies and jobs.

The change would be to turn the search controller's `this.api` into an array.

```
angular.module('SearchDemo', [])
.directive('search', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/search.tpl.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.results = [];

            // this.api is now an array and can support 
            // multiple custom search controllers
            this.api = [];
            this.addSearchAPI = function(searchAPI){
                if(this.api.indexOf(searchAPI) == -1){
                    this.api.push(searchAPI);
                }
            };

            $scope.doSearch = function(query){
                $scope.results.length = 0;

                // here we call each of the custom controller functions
                for(var i=0; i < this.api.length; i++){
                    var api = this.api[i];
                    if(angular.isFunction(api.getResults)){
                        var results = api.getResults(query);

                        $scope.results.push.apply($scope.results, results);
                    }
                }
            };
        }]
    };
})
.directive('searchCompanies', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['search', 'searchCompanies'],
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, Ctrl){
            // here we pass the custom search-companies controller
            // to the common search controller
            Ctrl[0].addSearchAPI(Ctrl[1]);
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            // you need to design your common search API and 
            // implement the custom versions of those functions here

            // example:
            this.getResults = function(query){
                // TODO: load the results for company search
            };
        }]
    };
})
.directive('searchJobs', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['search', 'searchJobs'],
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, Ctrl){
            // here we pass the custom search-jobs controller
            // to the common search controller
            Ctrl[0].addSearchAPI(Ctrl[1]);
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            // you need to design your common search API and 
            // implement the custom versions of those functions here

            // example:
            this.getResults = function(query){
                // TODO: load the results for job search
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

And using it in template would look like:

`<search search-companies search-jobs></search>`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass your data source or service to the directive and bind the events from there.

```
<body ng-app="customSearchDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Search a Company" data-custom-search data-source="companies" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for People" data-custom-search data-source="people" />

  <hr>
  Searching In: {{ searchSource }}
  <br/>
  Search Result is At: {{ results }}
</div>
</body>
```

In this sample I am using `data-source` to pass an array but you can use a service of course.

Then your directive should use the `scope` attribute to assign what you passed as parameter in `source` to the scope of the directive.

You will have the input that is using the directive in the `elem` parameter to bind all the parameters your desire.

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('customSearchDirective', [])


  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.companies = ['Microsoft', 'ID Software', 'Tesla'];
    $scope.people = ['Gill Bates', 'Cohn Jarmack', 'Melon Musk'];
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.searchSource = [];
  }])


  .directive('customSearch', [function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on("change", function(e) {
        var searchTerm = e.target.value;
        scope.$parent.$apply(function() {
          scope.$parent.searchSource = scope.source;
          scope.$parent.results = scope.source.indexOf(searchTerm);
        });
      });
    }

    return {
      scope: {
        source: '='
      },
      link: link
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Using `scope.$parent` feels a bit hacky I know and limits the use of this directive to be a direct child of the controller but I think it's a good way to get you started.

You can try it out: https://plnkr.co/edit/A3jzjek6hyjK4Btk34Vc?p=preview

Just a couple of notes from the example.

- The change event work after you remove focus from the text box (not while you're typing
- You will have to search the exact string to get a match

Hope it helps.